# WIFI Problem - Diconnected you are now offline

Tags: wireless

i'am new here. And Having problem with my wifi on let's say every 20-30 minitues on my Fujitsu AH531 laptop with ubuntu 14.10, saying "Diconnected you are now offline".I run the script suggested from some users here, and here is the wireless-info.txt file

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10577636/

I am running ubuntu alongside with Windows 7, but wifi on Win7 works just fine. Some help, please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the router settings for encryption/security to WPA2 only and set channel to channel 9.

Another change would be `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwl2.conf`
Reboot